# How to display the color of a button last clicked in java?

Tags: java

It is necessary that when the application is restarted, the last color that was displayed is displayed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io. *;

public class The extends JFrame {
    private JButton st1=new JButton("26");

    public The() {
        JPanel panel=new JPanel();
        panel.add(st1);
        st1.addActionListener(new Ac());
        add(panel);
    }

    class Ac implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Object source = e.getSource();
            if (((Component)source).getBackground().equals(Color.red)){
                ((Component)source).setBackground(null); //the color changing
            } else {
                ((Component)source).setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            try { //Here I threw the state of the button into color1.txt. The color of the button
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("color1.txt");
                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(f);
                out.writeObject(st1);
                System.out.println("File has been writen");
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException o) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        The window = new The();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(400,600);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("color1.txt");
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream);
    }
}
```

Now you need to display the color that was before closing when you restart the window. That is, if the color of the button was red to display red. If the color of the button is normal, the normal color is displayed.

Comment: You need to read the object from the objectInputStream. `JLabel label = (JLabel)objectInputStream.readObject();`

Comment: The answer to the title question is to write the color to persistent storage and read the value in when you start up the app.  It looks like you are trying this (using a file) but it is presumably not working as intended but you do not describe the discrepancy.  Consider writing a method to read in the value and another method to write out the value. Invoke the appropriate method on start up and shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the code, then the explanations.

```java
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class The extends WindowAdapter implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final String  PATH = "color1.dat";

    private Color  defaultBackground;
    private JButton  st1;
    private JFrame  frame;

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        if (source == st1) {
            Color col = st1.getBackground();
            if (col == defaultBackground) {
                st1.setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            else {
                st1.setBackground(defaultBackground);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndDisplayGui();
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.WindowAdapter
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
        Color background = st1.getBackground();
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(PATH);
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos)) {
            oos.writeObject(background);
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to save button background.", xIo);
        }
    }

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(this);
        st1 = new JButton("26");
        st1.addActionListener(this);
        defaultBackground = st1.getBackground();
        init();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(st1);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(PATH);
             ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis)) {
            Object obj = ois.readObject();
            if (obj instanceof Color) {
                Color bg = (Color) obj;
                st1.setBackground(bg);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException xFileNotFound) {
            // Ignore.
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException x) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read saved background", x);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new The());
    }
}
```

- In method `main` I explicitly launch the [*Event Dispatch Thread*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) (EDT). The parameter to method `invokeLater` is an instance of a class that implements interface `java.lang.Runnable` (which class `The` does). Hence method `invokeLater` will call method `run` in class `The`.
- Method `run` (in class `The`) calls method `createAndDisplayGui`. In this method I build the GUI.
- Method `createAndDisplayGui` calls method `init`. Method `init` tries to read the file that stores the last background color of `st1` (i.e. the `JButton`). Notice that the code uses [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and [multi-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html). Also note that the first time you run the app, the file may not exist. Hence I ignore `FileNotFoundException`.
- You only really want to save the background color of `st1` when you exit the app. Hence I added a [WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html). Method `windowClosing` is called just before the `JFrame` is closed.